# IOS, Loading files from app directory

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsfilemanager

I have app directory and I need to place some files in some place to use it in my app (free book). What directory should I use for it and how can I get path on it?

Comment: Visit this link and read about different directories in you app and their usage https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're including them in your app bundle when you're building it you can get the file path for them like this:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

If you're downloading them from a server or something then you should put them in the documents directory. This is obtained like so:

```
NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```

and then you can just append your file name to it to access it:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.pdf"];
```

If you just want the directory of the App Bundle and a directory listing you can do this:

```
NSString *appBundleFolderBath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
NSLog(@"App's Directory is: %@", appBundleFolderBath);
NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appBundleFolderBath]);
```

Comment: how can I work with directory from app bundle?

Comment: The first example will give you the path to your file in the app bundle if thats what you're after.

Comment: I've added another example about accessing the app's resource directory and listing the contents.

Comment: In my Xcode project I have directory 'TestBooks'. In it I have 'book1' directory. I need path to 'book1'. How can I get it?

Comment: Directories for source files in the XCode interface don't necessarily represent physical directories. All the files that are in the virtual directory "book1" are likely in the root application bundle folder upon compilation and installation. Run the last example I've put in my answer and see if the files are there.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you. By using this you can create files in the application data or fetch files from application data.

```
  var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
  var dirPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("XYZ/")

  var docPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("XYZ/xyz.json" )
  println(docPath)
  var checkImage = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

  if (checkImage.fileExistsAtPath(docPath)) {


} else
{
     checkImage.createDirectoryAtPath(dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)

}
```

For deleting specific use this

```
 checkImage.removeItemAtPath(imagePath, error: nil)
```